# How can I apply special relativity for sound?

Tags: special-relativity

What will happen if someone moving in a cart at speed of light shout(at same frequency) 
Can we expect a sonic boom in that case or something else will happen?

Comment: The phrase you are looking for is 'relativistic Doppler effect'

Comment: what do you mean "at the speed of light"?

Comment: @KyleKanos I ain't asking for change in frequency. Will there be an effect similar to observed for supersonic planes?

Comment: @JEB having speed close to that of light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is subsonic, transsonic, and supersonic--which are moving through a medium slower, around, and faster than the speed of sound in that medium. There is also hypersonic--which has various definitions in the aerospace industry, but physics-wise it means your a dissociating the atoms in the medium. Meteors and (re)entry spacecraft achieve this.

You are asking about ultra-relativistic. At these energies, the binding energy in the solids and even the atomic binding energies don't really matter, and you can consider the cart as a dense neutral plasma interacting with the atmosphere.

I think it's difficult to answer what exactly will happen. For a single piece of the car (an iron nucleus, for example), it will collide and create an air shower.

Note the kinetic energy of a small 1000 kg car traveling at minimum ionizing speed ($\gamma\approx 4$) which isn't even that close to the speed of light, then energy loss in the air will be:

$$ mc^2(\gamma-1) \approx 65 {\rm Teratons TNT}$$

It's just not reasonable to discuss sonic booms and sound propagation at this point.